# sqlite3 unable to open database

Tags: python-3.x, macos, sqlite

I am trying to write data on a database located on an external hard drive on macos.
As far as I can know, the sq3.Connection statement will test whether the database exists or not (and if not will create it)

When running the following

```
import sqlite3 as sq3
con = sq3.Connection('/Volumes/AGCM/MyDatabase.db')
```

I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I have checked the permissions and I have read&write access on this drive. One thing to note is that this was working fine until my old imac died and had to replace it with a macbook pro. I am using python 3.8 on this laptop.

I have databases on this hard drive and I can access and modify them via "DB Browser for SQLite"

Edit: it does work on the local directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. Although I had python 3x installed, the "native" mac version of python was being used ie python 2.7. After re-installing python with HomeBrew I now have full access in reading & writing to my external hard drive.